# 'value' can't be used as a setter because it's final

Tags: dart

How to fix next error? I need to set value, but it seems that it's `final`.

```
Future.forEach<MapEntry>(map.entries, (jsonMap) async {
    if (jsonMap.value is List) {
      await Future.forEach(jsonMap.value, (listItem) async {
        await KVToTableInsert(jsonMap.key, listItem);
      });
    }
    else {
         if(jsonMap.value == null)
         {
          savedValue = 0; //
          jsonMap.value = 0; // 'value' can't be used as a setter because it's final.
         }
    // ...
```

Comment: If you want to update the map entries you should properly use `updateAll` on the map: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/Map/updateAll.html . Alternative, you could make a normal for-each loop and update each key if needed.

Comment: @julemand101 could you show syntax for `updateAll`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `MapEntry` object from `entries` are read-only since you should not be able to update the key or value of each entry from the entry object but should do it on the map instead.

When I look at the code I think the major problem is that you are doing a little too much in the same forEach loop. So I think the easiest solution would be to spli the "set jsonMap.value to 0" logic from `KVToTableInsert`.

When updating the map you can e.g. use the `updateAll` method like this:

```
void main() {
  final jsonMap = {'a': null, 'b': 5};
  print(jsonMap); // {a: null, b: 5}

  jsonMap.updateAll((key, value) => value ?? 0);
  print(jsonMap); // {a: 0, b: 5}
}
```

You can then use the `forEach` method to iterate over all elements. Another note here is that I think it is much more readable to use a for-each construction instead of using `forEach` when you are that heavily using `async`.

**Updated**

Here is a more complete example of what I mean:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  final map = <String, dynamic>{
    'a': [1, 2, 3],
    'b': 5,
    'c': null
  };
  print(map); // {a: [1, 2, 3], b: 5, c: null}

  map.updateAll((key, dynamic value) => value ?? 0);
  print(map); // {a: [1, 2, 3], b: 5, c: 0}

  for (final jsonMap in map.entries) {
    if (jsonMap.value is List) {
      for (final listItem in jsonMap.value) {
        await KVToTableInsert(jsonMap.key, listItem);
      }
    } else {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

You can see that by using normal for-each loops we can skip a lot of `async` declarations and make it more simple to understand what is going on. And by handling the `null => 0` mapping before, we now know there cannot be any `value == null`.

Comment: I have copied next string to project and get error on it: 
```
jsonMap.updateAll((key, value) => value ?? 0);
// The method 'updateAll' isn't defined for the type 'MapEntry'.
```

Comment: Yes, because you should use it on the `Map` directly. In your case it would be `map`. And do it before even running your first `Future.forEach`.

Comment: > In your case it would be `map`

Please show me it's in code

Comment: Ok, I will try rewrite your example so it will work. It would be easier if you have provided a more complete example but I can properly guess what the types would be.